# Automatic compilation of classes in a threaded class. Please explain

Tags: java, multithreading

I noticed when i compile the class which is implemented as Runnable or extends Thread class, then the java class called from inside the protected void run() gets compiled along with it.

this is my code:

```
public class Main extends Thread{
    Main(){
        super("Main Thread-Entry Point");
        this.start();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Main();
    }
    public void run(){
        try{
            System.out.println("creating MDI and SQL threads");

            SQL sql = new SQL();
            sql.main(null);
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            MDI mdi = new MDI();
            mdi.main(null);

            System.out.println("thread created successfully");

        }
        catch(Exception ie){
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

i don't know if this a common thing that a java programmer should know generally.
please explain why this happens??

Comment: *All* code is compiled at once. Do you mean "run"? (Thread.start *invokes* Thread.run - which should be overloaded in subclasses - but I am otherwise unclear what is being asked or what the problem is.)

Comment: alright, you mean to say that any class present anywhere inside are compiled irrespective wheter its inside run() or somewhere else.??

Comment: if you are wondered about threads, so you may need start out a [java thread article](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html)

Comment: @RoshanJha 1) a class is compiled as a single unit; 2) all classes specified to `javac` (or other compiler) are compiled; 3) errors (for missing types/classes) will result if either the compiler or the runtime can't find appropriate dependencies (the compiler is smart enough to handle dependencies in source files that have been specified)

Comment: @user2864740: that info was very useful. thanx.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `javac` automatically compiles source files within your source path your code depends on.

Other IDEs even resolve the reverse dependency, compiling source files that are part of your project(s) and depend on the class you are just compiling.